# Dash: How to update hundreds of elements in callback?

Tags: python, html, css, plotly-dash, dashboard

In my Dash app, I have multiple `html.Div` components (all have nearly the same appearance and layout). Now, when I hit a checkbox, I want to hide all of these elements.
The solution everyone proposes is that you have multiple outputs, and address each id separately (see code below). The problem is, that I have around 50 of these Divs I would like to hide, and yet I have not given them a distinct id. If I would do it the way presented in the code down here, I would have to have a lot of outputs (around 50), and every time I add a new output, I would have to add it manually.

```
@app.callback(
    [Output(component_id='div-of-interest-1', component_property='style'),
     Output(component_id='div-of-interest-2', component_property='style'),
     .......]
    [Input(component_id='hide-checkbox', component_property='value')]
)
def hide_div(checked):
    if checked == 'True':
        return {'display': 'none'}
    else:
        return {'display': 'block'}
```

So, is there a smart way to address this problem? The simplest way (but not allowed) would be to have the same id for all divs that I want to hide. But this is prohibited from Dash. Is there something similar in Html, so that I can address all elements of interest at once?

Comment: Could you generate a list of the Div components programmatically so that you can assign an id to each of them programmatically. Then you could generate the inputs list for your callback programmatically as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it is not really possible within the current architecture. This would require some hacky code to make it work. There is not such thing as "tags" or something in html?

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the content of the Divs, you could generate a list of the Div components programmatically so that you can assign an id to each of them programmatically. For example

```
divs = [html.Div(id=f"div_{i}" <...> ) for i, x in enumerate(list_of_div_contents)]
```

These html.Div objects could possibly all be children of some other Div in your layout:

```
html.Div(id="div_parent", children=divs)
```

And your callback could potentially set `div_parent`'s children to `None`.